# Get an SSL certificate without revealing my clients postal address?

Tags: ssl

My client runs a blog site where he is an author with many published books and blogging is now his full time job.

The issue is he blogs about a lot of political topics, mainly things to do with terrorists and ISIS and that sort of thing.  He is constantly receiving death threats and his site has been hacked several times.

He is now wanting me to get and set up an SSL certificate.

The problem is for security reason on his life, he does not want to make his address a public data.

Is there a way to set up an SSL Certificate without revealing my clients address information?

Comment: 1) If EEAA's answer helped, please accept it. 2) What it the domain URL? It sounds like something I would be interested in, I would love to take a look.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're frequently required to provide an address (and additional verification information) for EV certs, but for "normal" certificates, you don't need to provide physical address information.

Comment: Normal certs just require proof that you have administrative access to the domain - recieving emails to postmaster@example.com is usually sufficient.

Comment: Or `hostmaster@example.com`, or `webmaster@example.com`